# Question on Indices and specifically solving for an indice that has the value "x"

Tags: exponentiation

Trying to workout   3(3$^x$) = 27$^{2x}$

So far i have done the following,

3(3$^x$)= 27$^{2x}$
(3)(3$^x$) = 27$^{2x}$
(3)+$x$= (9$^x$)(3$^x$)

Cant see what to do next...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you need to use the inverse of the exponential called a logarithm https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Comment: Appreciaite the reply. I think the poster below solved it without using the log but I can see where your coming from in regards using it. Thanks

Comment: technically he used the log  setting x+1=6x

Answer (score 1):

$$3\cdot \left( { 3 }^{ x } \right) ={ 27 }^{ 2x }\\ { 3 }^{ x+1 }={ \left( { 3 }^{ 3 } \right)  }^{ 2x }\\ { 3 }^{ x+1 }={ 3 }^{ 6x }\\ x+1=6x\\ x=0.2$$

Comment: that is literally so easy... how didnt I see that! Thanks so much!

Comment: you are welcome)